# FTP File - FileListFilter get only the newest file

Tags: java, spring, filter, ftp, spring-integration

I'm trying to implement something like this:

```
Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>(){
    public int compare(File f1, File f2)
    {
        return Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(f2.lastModified());
    } });
```

The problem is that I have `FTPFile` instead of `File`, and `FTPFile` has only getTimestamp().

How can I implement a filter to download only the newest file based on the modified date?

Or how can I tweak the example I showed to work with `FTPFile` instead of `File`?

It must look something like this:

```
public class NewestFileOnlyFilter implements FileListFilter<FTPFile> {
    //logic to return only the newest file.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can do that:

```
public class NewestFileOnlyFilter implements FileListFilter<FTPFile> {

  @Override
  public List<FTPFile> filterFiles(FTPFile[] files) {
    return Arrays.stream(files)                                         // 1
                 .max(Comparator.comparing(FTPFile::getTimestamp))      // 2
                 .map(Collections::singletonList)                       // 3
                 .orElse(Collections.emptyList());                      // 4
  }
}
```

Some clarification for referenced lines:

1. Represent the array in the form of a stream to simplify its further handling;
2. Main step:

   - searching for maximum element of the stream with `max` method;
   - providing `max` method with comparator with `Comparator.comparing`;
   - providing the comparator with a function that returns the key for comparison - `getTimestamp` in this case as we compare the files by their modification time.
3. Wrap the search result (file with maximum timestamp) into a list with single element (if any);
4. Otherwise return empty list.
   This is not likely to happen within `FileListFilter` but still we handle this case as well.

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp **is** (generally) the last modified time - see the javadocs...

```
/***
 * Returns the file timestamp.  This usually the last modification time.
 *
 * @return A Calendar instance representing the file timestamp.
 ***/
public Calendar getTimestamp()
```

`Calendar` implements `Comparable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
public int compare(File f1, File f2)
{
        Calendar dateOfmyFile=f1.getTimestamp();
        Date dateF1 =  dateOfmyFile.getTime();
        dateOfmyFile=f2.getTimestamp();
        Date dateF2 = dateOfmyFile.getTime();
        long difference = dateF1-dateF2;
        if(difference<0)
          return dateF2;
        else 
          return dateF1;
}
```